# Is there always a injective transform to decompose a function into a product?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose $f: R^2\to R$. Is there always an injective $T: R^2\to R^2$ such that $f(T(u,v))=g(u)h(v)$ for some $g:R\to R$ and $h:R\to R$?

Comment: What's an “almost surely injective” function?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I meant to write "almost everywhere". I just edited the question. It is not essential to the problem. Please check.